# spark-submit to a docker container

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, docker, spark-submit

I created a Spark Cluster using this [repository](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop-spark-workbench) and the relative documentation.

Now I'm trying to execute through `spark-submit` a job inside the Docker container of the Spark Master so the command that I use is something similar:

```
/path/bin/spark-submit --class uk.ac.ncl.NGS_SparkGATK.Pipeline \
--master spark://spark-master:7077 NGS-SparkGATK.jar HelloWorld
```

now the problem is that i receive `Failed to connect to master spark-master:7077`

I tried any combination: container IP, container ID, container name, localhost, 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 but I receive always the same error.

While if I use `--master local[*]` the application works.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you running the spark-submit from inside the container, or from the host machine?

Comment: Got it. I downvoted for same reason: its not very clear from the question where are you trying to execute spark-submit from. I came looking for an issue while submitting it from host machine -- so it was misleading for me. If you can clarify in the question, i'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @ksceriath any better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was to use the hostname for spark://spark-master:7077

So inside the Spark Master is something like this:

```
SPARK_MASTER_HOST=`hostname`

/path/bin/spark-submit --class uk.ac.ncl.NGS_SparkGATK.Pipeline \
--master spark://$SPARK_MASTER_HOST:7077 NGS-SparkGATK.jar HelloWorld
```

Comment: Are you running the spark-submit from inside the container, or from the host machine? Can you also explain how do you arrive at the `hostname` for the spark master container?

Comment: as I mentioned "inside the Spark Master" I reckon it was within the container. ` `hostname` ` surrounded by back-quotes is resolved as a Linux environment variable and passes the necessary argument to the spark command in this case